# laptop battery connector name

Tags: batteries, connector, laptop

I want to know what is the name or family name of the laptops' battery connectors? I want to replace a broken connector but don't know what to search for on digikey/mouser.
Image of connector below:

[image]

In specific I'm looking for the part number of the pavilion G6 battery connector. I found some connectors on aliexpress. No info or datasheet provided. It's like they're selling a bag of nuts:
http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Shelf-Taiwanese-laptop-battery-connector-9PIN/32482336723.html?spm=2114.01010208.3.2.6hTyPA&ws_ab_test=searchweb201556_7,searchweb201602_2_10057_10056_10055_10049_10059_10058_10017_10060_10061_10062_10063_412_10064,searchweb201603_2&btsid=a67c4079-f99d-47c9-a4c8-f5d6a4697e71

Any help/tip/thought is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a long time of intensive searching, I finally found the exact same component for my HP Pavilion G7. Its model number is EIO19, and is manufactured by ECE. The connector type is often called a "blade (type) connector" or a "laptop battery connector".

This question is probably long solved, but I'm providing this awnser for those who might be wondering what it's called.

Comment: LOL I ordered the components from Aliexpress after losing hope in finding it elsewhere (usually I don't order electronic components from aliexpress unless I am desperate). Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 5):

I believe it's called a **battery interconnect** on the sites.

[This](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Tyco%20Electonics%20AMP%20PDFs/Battery_Interconnects.pdf) is a datasheet that touches on the subject. A quick search on Digikey yielded a couple hundred results. Didn't see a 9-pin option, so maybe it's a proprietary design?

Hope this points you in the right direction!

Comment: Is there a way to find their respective pinouts, if this is non-standard? Do laptop vendors provide battery data-sheet? I could not find one.